# Removing a Polygon when using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've got a simple Google Map with two polygons defined and visible when a page loads.

I've tried adding buttons to turn off a polygon using ".setMap(null)", but it doesn't work for me.

Can you suggest a fix? I feel like I don't quite know enough without help. (you'll need a Google Maps API Key - sorry!).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Triangles</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<MAPS KEY GOES HERE>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
// Initialize a new map:
   const myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.73,-6.25);  // Center Point of map
   const myOptions = { zoom: 10, center: myLatLng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID }; // Map options
   const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions); // create "map"
// Define & draw a yellow triangle polygon:
   var yellowCoords = [ { lat: 55.828897, lng: -6.398249 }, { lat: 55.835067, lng: -6.126337 }, { lat: 55.674712, lng: -6.305552 } ];
   var yellowPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: yellowCoords, strokeColor: 'yellow', strokeOpacity: .7, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.2 });
   yellowPolygon.setMap(map);
// Define & draw a red triangle polygon:
   var redCoords = [ { lat: 55.668897, lng: -6.198249 }, { lat: 55.835067, lng: -6.026337 }, { lat: 55.674712, lng: -6.005552 } ];
   var redPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: redCoords, strokeColor: 'red', strokeOpacity: .7, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.2 });
   redPolygon.setMap(map);

} // end function initialize

function yellowOff() {
  yellowPolygon.setMap(null);
}
function redOff() {
  redPolygon.setMap(null);
}

</script>
<style> #map { height: 800px; width: 800px; }</style>
</head>

<body onLoad="initialize();">

<div id="map"></div>
<button onClick="javascript:yellowOff();" value="Click">Yellow Off</button>
<button onClick="javascript:redOff();" value="Click">Red Off</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have an obvious scope issue. Your Javascript console tells you that. *Uncaught ReferenceError: redPolygon is not defined* (same for the yellow one). You cannot declare variables within the `initialize` function and use these variables outside of it (in your other functions).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the comment by @MrUpsideDown regarding "Scope" You could either define these variables as globals and populate within the `initialize` function or keep everything contained within that `initialize` function as below. Further to that, by maintaining a single variable ( object literal in this case ) that contains references to the various polygons ( or other elements ) will allow easier manipulation of them when calling a function which is triggered by the buttons.

The buttons here will `toggle` the display of the polygons rather than simply hiding forever but to accomplish permanent hiding requires only a small change within the `clickhandler` callback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Triangles</title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:100%;height:90vh
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <button type='button' data-colour='yellow'>Yellow Off</button>
        <button type='button' data-colour='red'>Red Off</button>
        
        <script>
            function initialize(){
                const polygons={};
                const myLatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(55.73,-6.25);
                const myOptions = { 
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: myLatLng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                };
                const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), myOptions );
                
                let yellowCoords = [ { lat: 55.828897, lng: -6.398249 }, { lat: 55.835067, lng: -6.126337 }, { lat: 55.674712, lng: -6.305552 } ];
                let yellowPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: yellowCoords, strokeColor: 'yellow', strokeOpacity: .7, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.2 });
                    yellowPolygon.setMap( map );

                let redCoords = [ { lat: 55.668897, lng: -6.198249 }, { lat: 55.835067, lng: -6.026337 }, { lat: 55.674712, lng: -6.005552 } ];
                let redPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: redCoords, strokeColor: 'red', strokeOpacity: .7, strokeWeight: 2, fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.2 });
                    redPolygon.setMap(map);
                    
                polygons.yellow=yellowPolygon;
                polygons.red=redPolygon;
                
                const clickhandler=(e)=>{
                    let poly=polygons[e.target.dataset.colour]
                        poly.setMap( poly.getMap() ? null : map )
                }
                
                document.querySelectorAll('button[type="button"][data-colour]').forEach( bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',clickhandler) )
            }
        </script>
        <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initialize"></script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/ye9uwfba/3/) to show result